# Devise with Models User and Profile + Omniauth Facebook

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, devise, omniauth

Our App uses Devise for Registration and works perfect with User model and Profile model.

Save registration infos from form to Users table and create profile in Profiles table on SQL with another infos and nested with user_id.

The Omniauth Facebook is working to save things to User model, but I want save name, username fetched from Facebook Auth to Profile model like the Devise registration do.

---

**TABLE Users**

```
| id | email | encrypted_password | reset_password_token | reset_password_sent_at | remember_created_at | sign_in_count | current_sign_in_at | last_sign_in_at | current_sign_in_ip | last_sign_in_ip | created_at | updated_at | role_id | provider | uid |
```

**TABLE Profiles**

```
| id | user_id | username | name | lastname | gender | birthday | created_at | updated_at |
```

---

**MODEL User.rb**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_one :profile, :dependent => :destroy, autosave: true
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :profile

  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable, :omniauthable, :omniauth_providers => [:facebook]

  belongs_to :role
  before_create :set_default_role

  def self.find_for_facebook_oauth(auth)
    where(auth.slice(:provider, :uid)).first_or_create do |user|
      user.provider = auth.provider
      user.uid = auth.uid
      user.email = auth.info.email
      user.password = Devise.friendly_token[0,20]
    end
  end

  def self.new_with_session(params, session)
    super.tap do |user|
      if data = session["devise.facebook_data"] && session["devise.facebook_data"]["extra"]["raw_info"]
        user.email = data["email"] if user.email.blank?
      end
    end
  end

  private
  def set_default_role
    self.role ||= Role.find_by_name('registered')
  end

end
```

**MODEL Profile.rb**

```
class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :user

  validates :username, presence: true, length: {maximum: 255}, uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }, format: { with: /\A[a-zA-Z0-9]*\z/, message: "deve contar apenas letras e números" }
  validates :name, presence: true, length: {maximum: 255}
  validates :lastname, presence: true, length: {maximum: 255}
  validates :gender, presence: true, inclusion: %w(m f)
  validates :birthday, presence: true

end
```

---

**CONTROLLER application_controller.rb (to handle the permits of custom fields)**

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  # Prevent CSRF attacks by raising an exception.
  # For APIs, you may want to use :null_session instead.
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception

  before_action :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

  protected

  def configure_permitted_parameters
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) { |u| u.permit(:email, :password, :password_confirmation, :provider, :uid, profile_attributes: [:name, :lastname, :username, :birthday, :gender, :id]) }
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_in) { |u| u.permit(:email, :password, :remember_me, :provider, :uid) }
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:account_update) { |u| u.permit(:username, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :current_password) }
  end

end
```

---

Anyone knows how can I make Omniauth Facebook runs like Devise registration to create profile for the user, integration the two models User and Profile without break the Devise registration too :P ?

Thank you :)

Comment: try this `user.profile.name = auth.info.name`

Comment: @anonymousxxx i tried it first before post, returned error: undefined method `name=' for nil:NilClass

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know facebook sign up or sign in flow of your app so i'm just going to assume that when a user clicks on sign in or sign up with facebook, your app basically fetches email from the facebook and create a new user only if that email is not present in db else it just sign them in.

To achieve this you need to override your `find_for_facebook_oauth(auth)` method. You can do something like this in your method

```
def self.find_for_facebook_oauth(auth)
  if user = User.find_by_email(auth.info.email)  # search your db for a user with email coming from fb
    return user  #returns the user so you can sign him/her in
  else
    user = User.create(provider: auth.provider,    # Create a new user if a user with same email not present
                       uid: auth.uid,
                       email: auth.info.email,
                       password: Devise.friendly_token[0,20])
    user.create_profile(name: auth.info.name, # you need to check how to access these attributes from auth hash by using a debugger or pry
                        #your other profile attributes

                        )
    return user

  end
end
```

and then your callback method will be same

```
class Users::OmniauthCallbacksController < Devise::OmniauthCallbacksController
  def facebook
    # You need to implement the method below in your model (e.g. app/models/user.rb)
    @user = User.find_for_facebook_oauth(request.env["omniauth.auth"])

    if @user.persisted?
      sign_in_and_redirect @user, :event => :authentication #make sure user is confirmed else it'll throw an error
      set_flash_message(:notice, :success, :kind => "Facebook") if is_navigational_format?
    else
      session["devise.facebook_data"] = request.env["omniauth.auth"]
      redirect_to new_user_registration_url
    end
  end
end
```

If your flow is like Yahoo where you render a form with autofilled fields using the data coming from facebook then instead of creating you can simply initialise `user` and `profile` inside `find_for_facebook_oauth(auth)` method with statements

```
user = User.new(#user attributes)
user.build_profile(#profile attributes)
return user # and then return initialised user
```

Since the user is not in db it will execute the else block in facebook callback method and will render sign in page with fields autofilled.

Answer (score 0):

Here is where devise saves your info from omniauth

```
def self.find_for_facebook_oauth(auth)
  where(auth.slice(:provider, :uid)).first_or_create do |user|
    user.provider = auth.provider
    user.uid = auth.uid
    user.email = auth.info.email
    user.password = Devise.friendly_token[0,20]
  end
end
```

so just add the fields you want to save in there

```
user.username = auth.info.nickname
```

if you want to see the hash in real time raise an exception in the callbacks

```
class Users::OmniauthCallbacksController < Devise::OmniauthCallbacksController
   def facebook
     raise request.env["omniauth.auth"].to_yaml # <----------
     .
     .
     .
```

or in [omniauth-facebook-gem](https://github.com/mkdynamic/omniauth-facebook) page they have an example, raise an exception is useful for debugging in some cases , *regards*

Comment: Thanks @Alexis but that should work only if save to User model. I want facebook data saved in User model and Profile model

Comment: same deal then, suppose you have a user who has_one user_profile, in the same location add user.user_profile.some_info = auth.some_info, you should add a builder in a before_create action for your user_profile, with that you will have a new user_profile associated, in like 5 hrs i will have my laptop with me and i'll let you a copy of a approch that i use in a project, regards